# How to generalize using $ie for different pages levels ($ie1...)

Tags: ruby, class, watir

I have a class which checks to see if a page title exists. I need to execute it several times. In every case I operate in different levels of ie - ie1, ie2. In my code I check $ie, how can I generalize this for $ie1 and so on?

```
class Text_neg
def initialize(text, object)
@text=text
@object=object
if $ie.contains_text(@text)
puts("Test for " + @object + " failed")
puts ($ie.link(:text => /Exception:/))
h= $ie.link(:text => /Exception:/)
$r.addtoReport($testReport, "check " + @object, "FAILED", h.text) 
else
puts("Test for " + @object + " passed")
$r.addtoReport($testReport, "check " + @object, "PASSED", "Test for " + @object + "    passed" )
end
end
end
```

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize your Text_neg class, you should pass in the ie object you want to use. Then the Text_neg can store it in a variable that it knows about and does not have to be incremented for each ie object.

It would look something like:

```
class Text_neg
  def initialize(text, object, ie)
    @text=text
    @object=object
    @ie=ie

    if @ie.contains_text(@text)
      puts("Test for " + @object + " failed")
      puts (@ie.link(:text => /Exception:/))
      h= @ie.link(:text => /Exception:/)
      $r.addtoReport($testReport, "check " + @object, "FAILED", h.text) 
    else
      puts("Test for " + @object + " passed")
      $r.addtoReport($testReport, "check " + @object, "PASSED", "Test for " + @object + "    passed" )
    end
  end
end
```

Then to run this for each IE object, you would do:

```
Text_neg(text, object, $ie1)
Text_neg(text, object, $ie2)
etc
```